# Cannot extend virtual disk in storage space with free space

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

On my Windows Server 2012 R2 I have a storage pool capacity of 2.22TB and 516GB free space, however I cannot extend my virtual disk past 1.72TB. The UI will let me create another virtual disk with the 512GB capacity but not extend into it.

[storage pool layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78ukl.png)

On my other box I can get full capacity allocated.

[storage pool layout 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQrE6.png)

How do I get it to let me extend my virtual disk into that free space?

Comment: Off hand I do not know, but it may be worth dropping into powershell and do a get-virtualdisk | fl of both systems, and compare item by item and see if anything relevant looks different.  The GUI hides a lot from you.  Seems doubtful (with two each), were both pools created initially with both physical disks present and unchanged since?   Adding disks later vs initially can also create differences in structure under the covers.  Same format (NTFS vs ReFS)?

Comment: The only difference I can see bar the writecache on the other server (it's tiered with a SSD) is that It has two columns. What effect would that have on the problem?

Comment: I'll let someone who understands better answer but I think the answer *may* be yes.  I'm not even sure how you can have two columns given the size of the drives, but columns affect how disks can be added, and may well affect whether files can span disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to sort my problem out by recreating the storage pool with just 1 disk, creating the virtual disk with 1 column and then adding the second disk and expanding. Would have been nice for a less destructive route but it did fix the problem, full capacity used now.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The two columns are the reason for this.
It means, each "piece" of data in the virtual disk is "split" between the two physical drives. So when the smaller drive is used up, it can not extend beyond that.
So the maximum space you can use is the size of the smaller disk (882 GB) multiplied by two (is about 1764 GB , 1.72 in TB).

A bit annoying as the column count is barely mentioned in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue on Google cloud.  We have a SQL Cluster on Google Cloud running Server 2019.

We solved this  by this method

Get-VirtualDisk |fl

- note the number of Columns.  Ours was 4.

We had to add FOUR disks to each server of the cluster (2 servers, so total of 8 disks) before we were allowed to extend the virtual disk from the available storage pool.  You can do this from Server Manager - FIle and Storage Services - Storage Pools - Right click on the virtual disk and click expand.

There was still an additional step.  The actual disk D:\ also had to be expanded.  Under Volumes right click on D:\ and expand it.  (I am not 100% sure I am remember this part correctly - I'm sure about the other part).

Also note YOU CANNOT just expand the size of the disk in Google Cloud like you can with a simple disk.  You can expand it but it does nothing, and now you can't reduce the size, so you are stuck paying for that increased cost.  The only way to increase size is to add disks under google cloud in sets of the number of Columns (in our case 4), then expand the disk.